# pandas clients table >> add edges to a nodes column and deltatimes

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a data table I would like to create a graph. (see data example for pasting at the end)
For that I would like to create the nodes and the edges.
Every client go through different process states.
The edges connect two states (nodes)
My aim is to get the edges as shown in the excel table screenshot and the delta time of every time change.

My code:
First I sorted the table by client and by timestamp (i.e. the nodes (states) go from t1 to t2 to t3 ... where t1

```
estados=estados.sort_values(['CLIENT', 'timestamp'], ascending=[True, True])
```

And now follows a 20% pythonic code and 0% pandonic code:

```
edges_column = []
delta_column = []
for client in list_of_clients:
    client_df = estados.loc[estados['CLIENT'] == client,['node','timestamp']]
    client_nodes      = client_df['node']
    client_timestamps = client_df['timestamp']
    list_edges        = [node1 + '-' + node2 for node1,node2 in  zip(client_nodes[:-1],client_nodes[1:])]
    list_delta_times  = [t2 -t1 for t1,t2 in  zip(client_timestamps[:-1],client_timestamps[1:])]
    print(list_edges)
    print(list_delta_times)
    # adding ['-'] because if there are n nodes there are n-1 edges. the same for delta times
    edges_column = edges_column + list_edges + ['-']
    delta_column = delta_column + list_delta_times + ['-']

# adding the columns edges_column and delta_column
print(len(edges_column))
estados['edge']      = edges_column
estados['deltatime'] = delta_column
```

This code works but it is far from ideal.
This should be a pretty common problem. I need a more efficient code because I have half a million rows and it should run in a reasonable time.

I am looking for a function to create the columns edge and timestamp
I can not come to such a solution because the function is referring to values out of two different rows and not only to ony, in such a case I could do something like

```
estados['edge'] = estados['node'].apply(function)
```

because I have to pass two values not only one.

Is there at all a way without using for loops?

thx.

[image]

the table is in pandas format:

NOTE1 for copy and paste JSON file: {"CLIENT":{"0":"client1","1":"client1","2":"client1","3":"client1","4":"client2","5":"client2","6":"client2","7":"client3","8":"client4","9":"client4","10":"client4","11":"client4","12":"client4","13":"client4"},"node":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"H","4":"B","5":"F","6":"G","7":"C","8":"D","9":"E","10":"F","11":"H","12":"G","13":"K"},"timestamp":{"0":1590684862000,"1":1590771262270,"2":1590857662000,"3":1590598462000,"4":1590425662000,"5":1590512062000,"6":1590598462000,"7":1590771262270,"8":1588352062000,"9":1588524862000,"10":1588611262000,"11":1588697662000,"12":1588956862000,"13":1589043262000}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`df.shift`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [**`pd.Series.str.cat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) here.

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('CLIENT').node.shift(1).str.cat(df.node,'-')
df

     CLIENT node      timestamp result
0   client1    A  1590684862000    NaN
1   client1    B  1590771262270    A-B
2   client1    C  1590857662000    B-C
3   client1    H  1590598462000    C-H
4   client2    B  1590425662000    NaN
5   client2    F  1590512062000    B-F
6   client2    G  1590598462000    F-G
7   client3    C  1590771262270    NaN
8   client4    D  1588352062000    NaN
9   client4    E  1588524862000    D-E
10  client4    F  1588611262000    E-F
11  client4    H  1588697662000    F-H
12  client4    G  1588956862000    H-G
13  client4    K  1589043262000    G-K
```

Comment: wonderful. works. I am trying to use also shift for the deltatime.

Comment: df.groupby('CLIENT').timestamp.shift(1).substract(df.timestamp)     does not work....

Comment: @Berlines Use `df.groupby('CLIENT').timestamp.shift(1).sub(df.timestamp)`

Comment: when using df.groupby('CLIENT').timestamp.shift(1).sub(df.timestamp) the deltatimes are negative. why if they are ordered from first ocurrence to last ocurrence

Comment: here the solutioni: df.groupby('CLIENT').timestamp.shift(-1).sub(df.timestamp)